# How can I delete a keychain password for github and vscode? || Delete Keychain with Terminal

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-git

What I am facing the way worked previously deleting a keychain password from UI is not working anymore, simply it doesn't delete or trigger any error messages. STRANGE !!

Now I want to delete it using terminal. How can i do that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

do these commands in terminal :

```
 git credential-osxkeychain erase ⏎
 host=github.com  ⏎
 protocol=https   ⏎
 ⏎
 ⏎
```

⏎ this is the return key .